# React - redux state mutation error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend, mutation

I am trying to add an section to a survey object and its throwing state mutation error.

this is the method where im calling the action creator which takes the entire survey object as an argument.

```
   addNewSection(sectionName){
   const id = performance.now();
    let newSurvey = Object.assign({}, this.state.survey);
    const section = Object.assign({},{
        "type": "section",
        "id": id,
        "title": sectionName,
        "position": {
            "offset": 0,
            "width": 12,
            "order": 1
        },
        "items": []
    });
    newSurvey.layout.sections.push(section);
    this.setState({survey: newSurvey});
    this.props.actions.updateSurvey(newSurvey);
}
```

action Creator:

```
export function updateSurvey(survey){
return {type:types.ADD_SECTION_SUCCESS, survey};
}
```

reducer:

```
export default function surveyReducer(state = initialState.survey, action){
switch(action.type){

    case types.ADD_SECTION_SUCCESS:
        return action.survey;

    default:
         return state
    }    
}
```

the state object is of the form:

```
survey: {
layout: {
    sections: [{},{},{}]
    },
    questions:[{},{},{}]
}
```

I must be misunderstanding Object.assign. Does Object.assign make a copy of every single nested object inside the survey, if i just use it at the very top level of the survey Object like i used it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the solutions mentioned above are completely wrong. Object.assign and ES6 spread operators never work on deeply nested data structures such as yours. They WON'T prevent any state mutations.

Secondly, state mutation errors are ALWAYS related to REDUX's state and NOT the local state.

```
export default function headerReducer(state = {userName: ''}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SSO_USER_ACTION':
        {
            return Object.assign({}, state, { userName: action.payload });
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Check out the above sample reducer. Here we always return a new object by using:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, { userName: action.payload });
```

However, in your case, the state object 'survey' is not that simple. It is deeply nested and the Object.assign OR the spread operator won't help at all to prevent a mutation. You have 3 options:

1. Use immutable JS library which provides maps and lists which can never be mutated.
2. Use a normalization library to flatten your state.
3. (a Dirty approach which requires no extra library) Fix the mutation using below solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting a little confused on where state should be mutated. It looks like you are not using the redux state at all in your addNewSection function. You are just updating local component state. You do not even need to use object.assign here you can update local state and mutate it anyway you like.

You mutate your state in your reducer when you return your new survey as the as the survey state.

You need to use connect and mapStateToProps() to access your survey state from props. Then you can use your object.assign logic in your reducer to return a new copy of the state.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { survey: state.survey }
}
```

You can access survey from this.props.survey and display it where you want.

You dont need object.assign at all in your addNewSection() function. Just make your new section variable, pass it to your action creator, your action creator will dispatch it to your reducer which you will use object.assign to return a new copy of state which will be updated on your this.props.survey.

also, it is reccomended to use the object spread syntax over object.assign for better syntax see here: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html

and

here for tips on using mapStateToProps:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: I 100% agree with you and i used to do that way. But my lead recommended to do this way.. he is also new to react by the way. So i used this method.
lets say i do as you say, in the reducer, do i have to something like this:
 return Object.assign({},survey,{
            layout: Object.assign({},survey.layout,{
                items: [...survey.layout.items, section]
            })
        });

of just this:
return Object.assign({}, survey}

in other words, do i have to make a copy of every single object inside the survey or just the survey.

Comment: I always do it like this and its easy to understand. It would look like: 
     { ...state, survey: action.survey }

this is equal to:

    Object.assign({}, state, {
            survey: action.survey
          })

Basically you are replacing your old state but not keeping the same object. Object.assign() returns a new object.

Comment: EDIT: sorry didn't read the question right. No you do not need to use nested Object.assigns. Just use the one Object.assign() to copy over state into a new object.

Object.assign() copies state into the empty object, then copies the third argument over top. therefore it doesn't mutate anything, just makes a copy with that empty object!

Comment: isnt that what i did in the component about? i used Object.assign({},survey)
which makes a copy of the survey and then i pushed the section into it and then sent the entire survey object into redux in this.props.actions.updateSurvey(newSurvey);
statement. Am i missing something? when i do this im getting mutation error. if i Object assign like this:
let newSurvey = Object.assign({},survey,{
            layout: Object.assign({},survey.layout,{
                items: [...survey.layout.items, section]
            })
        });
it works.

Comment: @vineeth Where are you doing the object.assign call? Are you referring to in the component, or in the reducer? I am getting confused here. The reason you get the mutation error is from the reducer. The component should not have anything to do with it.

Comment: @vineeth my apologies man, I misunderstood a bit. You ARE mutating your component state which is where you are getting error. Object.assign does not do a deep clone. It just copies the object property values. When you push a new section onto newSurvey that actually does mutate this.state.survey as well because the nested objects are just references. This all has nothing to do with redux. Are you actually getting an error or just a warning here?

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the object in ES6 way using spread operator:

```
let newSurvey = {...this.state.survey}
```